# How can I get records from Firebase where a certain field is empty

Tags: firebase

I'm building an app where I need to process 5k+ tasks in small batches. For that I have a queue of tasks that is stored in a Firebase. I'd like to be able to pull certain amount of tasks with empty status, update their status and write back.

Currently I don't see how I can pull data where a certain field is empty. Is it possible? If not, what would be the alternative solution?

**UPDATED 02/12**. Here is the data structure that I have:

```
{
  "-KAMnc89C5Yi_ef18ewc" : {
    "0": {
      "url": "https://excample.com/url",
      "status": "done"
    },
    "1": {
      "url": "https://excample.com/url1"
    },
    "2": {
      "url": "https://excample.com/ur2"
    },
    "3": {
      "url": "https://excample.com/ur3"
    }
}
```

And this is the query I'm using:

```
queueRef.orderByChild('status').equalTo(null).limitToFirst(1).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

`queueRef` points to `"-KAMnc89C5Yi_ef18ewc"` from the data above.

I expect to get one object - "1", but instead I'm getting all of them. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

Firebase doesn't allow you to store a property without a value. That simply means that the property doesn't exist.

Luckily this doesn't really matter too much, because this seems to work. Given this data structure:

```
{
  "-KADbswYg3FiQF78mmUf": {
    "name": "task1",
    "status": "done"
  },
  "-KADbugr7QzTx0s93Fs0": {
    "name": "task2"
  },
  "-KADbvKvBgiAXxnQvoBp": {
    "name": "task3"
  }
}
```

This works:

```
ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo(null).once('value', function(snapshot) { 
  console.log(snapshot.val()); 
})
```

This prints `task2` and `task3`.

Comment: I was actually surprised that it did. ;-)

Comment: up1 for your speedy typing skills

Comment: Thanks! I'm storing a property with empty string, but will probably convert that to match your suggestion. Another quick question, if I want to limit data set, I can do so with startAt and endAt functions, right?

Comment: `.orderByChild('status').equalTo("")` works too. Next time add your JSON (as text, not a screenshot) to your question so that we know what you have.

Comment: `startAt()` and `endAt()` do the same as `equalTo`. You're probably looking for `limitToFirst()`. All of this is quite decently documented in the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries)

Comment: Sorry Frank, I tried your solution and it didn't work for me. Probably I'm still missing something. Updated the question with more details. Will appreciate further explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, interestingly enough this worked when I tried it last time, but fails now. I was surprised to see it work, so expect that we're now back to the expected behavior: **you cannot test for the absence of a value**. Luckily, you said you had empty strings, so test for those and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the *DataSnapshot.exists()*

This will returns true if this snapshot contains any data. If not it will return false. According to the documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/exists.html). It is slightly more efficient than using snapshot.val() !== null.

With a data structure like this:

```
{
  "girlfriend": {
    "first": "Pamala",
    "last": "Anderson"
  }
}
```

And a firebase call like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://myURL/girlfriend/Pamala");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var a = snapshot.exists();
  // a === true

  var b = snapshot.child("girlfriend").exists();
  // b === true

  var c = snapshot.child("girlfriend/first").exists();
  // c === true

  var d = snapshot.child("girlfriend/middle").exists();
  // d === false (because there is no "name/middle" girlfriend in the data snapshot)
});
```