# Get data from Firebase database using child name from unknown push key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using android studio ( android )
how to Get data from Firebase database 
using child value from unknown pushed key 
as you can see in the picture  friends 
I'm trying to get data where

> topicimage4 = 0

But I don't have the **random key** Firebase pushed

Firebase database

[image]

I searched alot about this Issue but I didn't found anything or 
I found questions with no answers in this website 
I tried also the following

```
myRef.child("*").orderByChild("topicimage4").equalTo("0")
myRef.child("?").orderByChild("topicimage4").equalTo("0")
myRef.orderByChild("topicimage4").equalTo("0")
myRef.orderByKey().orderByChild("topicimage4").equalTo("0")
```

**UPDATE**

here my Json tree as text

Is there any way to access to the topicimage4 child without having the Randrom key ? thnx

```
{
  "-L5YppUZa3dGBvDUgnYi" : {
    "paidmoney" : "400",
    "paidmoneytype" : "1",
    "topiccat" : "1",
    "topiccon" : "0",
    "topicemail" : "",
    "topicimage1" : "null",
    "topicimage2" : "null",
    "topicimage3" : "null",
    "topicimage4" : "0",
    "topicimage5" : "21",
    "topicname" : "مطلوب انسات للعمل ضمن صالون نسائي طريق عام جزين",
    "topicphone" : "70645725",
    "topicresouresname" : "",
    "topicresouresurl" : "",
    "topictext" : "في حال طلب منك الاتصال دولار اضافي على الدقيقة قم بإغلاق الخط \r\n\r\nمطلوب انسات للعمل ضمن صالون نسائي طريق عام جزين\r\n\r\n\r\nنحن نحاول قدر الامكان ضبط جميع انواع الوظائف المقدمة نشكر لكم اهتمامكم ومساعدتكم\r\n",
    "topictimed" : "17",
    "topictimeh" : "01",
    "topictimei" : "57",
    "topictimem" : "02",
    "topictimey" : "18",
    "userimage" : "0"
  },
  "-L5Yq6VJoOAN7dUKDO9O" : {
    "paidmoney" : "400",
    "paidmoneytype" : "1",
    "topiccat" : "1",
    "topiccon" : "0",
    "topicemail" : "",
    "topicimage1" : "null",
    "topicimage2" : "null",
    "topicimage3" : "null",
    "topicimage4" : "0",
    "topicimage5" : "0",
    "topicname" : "يلزمنا انسه ذات مظهر لائق",
    "topicphone" : "81614696",
    "topicresouresname" : "",
    "topicresouresurl" : "",
    "topictext" : "في حال طلب منك الاتصال دولار اضافي على الدقيقة قم بإغلاق الخط \r\n\r\nيلزمنا انسه زات مظهر لائق للعمل في اكس برس عالاوتستراد بدوام كامل للمراجعه وتس اب التفاصيل موجوده كامله\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nنحن نحاول قدر الامكان ضبط جميع انواع الوظائف المقدمة نشكر لكم اهتمامكم ومساعدتكم\r\n",
    "topictimed" : "17",
    "topictimeh" : "01",
    "topictimei" : "58",
    "topictimem" : "02",
    "topictimey" : "18",
    "userimage" : "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The JSON you shared doesn't have a `topicimage4` property. So I assume you want to get the topics without that property. In that case, try `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.ref("topic").orderByChild("topicimage4").equalTo(null)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330692/how-can-i-get-records-from-firebase-where-a-certain-field-is-empty

Comment: sorry i uploaded the wrong image
it does have a topicimage4 property
 I just want a way to access the child without the random key

Comment: Please update the JSON that you're trying to query. While you're doing that, be sure to post it as text instead of a screenshot. You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 
thnx for your replay 
I updated my question

Comment: It works fine i'm sorry i'm was trying to make two queries 
like this 
orderByChild("topicimage4").equalTo("0").orderByChild("topicimage3").equalTo("null")
but when i removed the  second  query it works fine

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase.